# numpy three-tuple array to RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a numpy-array `[i,j]` with depth-values. For each cell in the array, I wish to assign them a pre-defined colour. I currently do that with `np.vectorize` and a lot of `if`-statements. I can now make something I need like `(245,223,247)` as an example.

Can I create a new numpy array and export that one as a `.png`-image?

This is the array I have:

```
[[r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b]
 [r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b]
 [r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b]
 [r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b],[r,g,b]]
```

And I want to translate that into a .png image.

**edit:**
[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/willemvanopstal/76c2c762a340f1ea634bcb3f39a1723d) is an example of the `depth`-array, printed to text. It is too large to display in python. It also shows the function I'd like to apply to every cell to create the rgb-color.

This is a sample image in greyscale. Based on the units above. [image]

Comment: Do you want to create an image and fill it with `(245,223,247)` color ?

Comment: Colorize each pixel and export it indeed.

Comment: How are the depth values stored? Please show a small working example.

Comment: I've updated my question with a sample dataset and the coloring-function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest (and most fair) solution is to use a colormap. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

N         = 256
cols      = np.zeros((N,4))
cols[:,0] = np.linspace(0,1,N) # R
cols[:,1] = np.linspace(0,1,N) # G
cols[:,2] = np.linspace(0,1,N) # B
cols[:,3] = 1                  # alpha
cmap      = colors.ListedColormap(cols,name='MyColormap',N=N)

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,100),np.linspace(0,1,100))
d   = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.imshow(d,cmap=cmap,clim=[0,np.sqrt(2.)])

cbar = fig.colorbar(cax,aspect=10)

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(range(0,101,20))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(range(0,101,20))

plt.xlim([0,100])
plt.ylim([0,100])

plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')

plt.savefig('so.png')
```

This result is as follows:

[image]

Note that the example includes a custom (but quite trivial gray-scale) colormap, which should suit your purpose. You can also use the predefined ones (e.g. by `cmap='afmhot'`), see [the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

If you want a discrete set of colors, you can simply apply thresholding to your data (`d` in this case).

> Your question was a bit too broad for me to specialize this to your example. For us to help you, you should formulate more concisely, in words, what you mean. But I am sure you can progress independently from here.

Comment: matplotlib has a function too to make your own [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors)

Comment: @MaartenFabré You are right that this is an important addition to this answer. I have edited my answer to include an example.